# quilt pop without undoing local edits

Tags: quilt

Is there a way of doing a `quilt pop` without undoing changes made locally to the files that the pop touches in lines that were not affected by the patch?

I want to just revert the patch, not reset the file to the state it had when the patch was applied.

Thank you